# js: one confusing point about 'this' keyword usage between ES5 and ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6, this

I am currently learning ES6 standard, for the arrow function part, I found a confusing point as following:

```
function foo() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('id:', this.id);
    }, 100);
}

var id = 21;

foo.call({ id: 42 });
```

the above is ES6 standard, and ES5 is as following

```
function foo() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('id:', this.id);
    }, 100);
}

var id = 21;

foo.call({ id: 42 });
```

`In ES5, the output is id:21` 
`In ES6, the output is id:42`

I can understand the ES6's result. But very confused with the result from ES5. The call site for foo() function is `foo.call({id:42})`,so the calling object is {id:42}, but when it executes, the calling object changes to window. How so?

Comment: You should always `"use strict"` mode.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is that not the call site of `foo` changes, but that the `function` passed to `setTimeout` has a different call site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few pieces here. First off, understand that `this` is essentially an argument that is automatically set by the thing calling the function. That is critical to understand. So in this case, `setTimeout` is responsible for calling your function and it essentially does `fn.call(undefined)`, so no explicit `this` is passed in.

Next, your examples:

```
function foo() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('id:', this.id);
  }, 100);
}
```

vs

```
function foo() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('id:', this.id);
  }, 100);
}
```

The arrow function case is essentially:

```
function foo() {
  var _this = this;

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('id:', _this.id);
  }, 100);
}
```

So comparing `this` in the two cases, the first uses the `this` that `foo` is called with, and your example code works because you're `foo.call({ id: 42 });` explicitly sets than. The second example uses the `this` that `setTimeout` passes, which as I mentioned above is `undefined`.

However, the `this` that is passed in from `.call` *may* not actually be the `this` that ends up exposed inside the function.

- In non-strict code: `this` is passed straight through, if it is an object, but if it is *not* an object, `this` is the global object (`window` in a browser, `global` in Node)
- In strict code: `this` is passed straight through unchanged

Since your example code is has not been marked with `"use strict";`, this means you are hitting this global behavior. This means your two examples are essentially this:

```
function foo() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('id:', window.id); // reads "id" from the global object
  }, 100);
}
```

vs

```
function foo() {
  var _this = this;

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('id:', _this.id); // reads "this" from `foo.call(...)`
  }, 100);
}
```

The last piece here is that your

```
var id = 21;
```

is in the global scope, so it is essentially doing `window.id = 21`. Thus this value carries through.

The main takeaways here that I'd recommend:

- Don't execute code in the top-level scope so that your `var` declarations don't end up on `window`. This will happen automatically if you use a module system like CommonJS or Webpack's ES6 module syntax. If you do this, your code as-is would log `undefined` since `window.id` would not exist.
- Always mark your code with `"use strict";`. This usually is easy. If you're using CommonJS just put it at the top of your file, and if you're using ES6 modules, it will be added automatically because ES6 modules are required to be strict. If you do this, `this` inside your non-arrow callback would be `undefined` so `this.id` would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

ES5: 'this' is verified until function actually called (i.e., function() or by 'new' keyword). In your case, the callback function inside setTimeout is actually invoked by window object (hence your 'this' turns out to be window object), and window object has 'a' attribute since you declared. That's why it prints out 21.

ES6: 'this' is verified once your function is declared. Hence 'this' points to ANYTHING inside 'call' function. Of course you can try call(window), then you will see 21 is printed out as expected since window has 'a=21' attribute.

This is a really good question and I hope above explanation helps:)